# Lost content when emailing CHM files

Tags: chm, email-attachments

I want to send someone a CHM file via email.

When they receive the file they can open the contents, see the object browser but all content simply says "Navigation to the webpage was canceled".

I can see the contents of the origin

The help file is Html Help 1.x as generated by Innovasys DocumentX 2011.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is normal. Since XPSP2 downloaded CHM's get a "downloaded" attribute that prohibit the CHM viewer (MSIE) to show the content.

To fix this, take the properties of the CHM file and choose the "unblock" option

If you want to do this from a program, you need to truncate additional NTFS filestreams. (see the Free Pascal "chmls unblock" command as example).

The relevant Delphi code looks like this:

```
procedure unblockchm(s:string);
var f : file;
begin
  writeln('unblocking ',s);
  assignfile(f,s+':Zone.Identifier');
  rewrite(f,1);
  truncate(f);
  closefile(f);
end;
```